# Spring MVC - HTTP Status 404 error. Anything missing in web.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web.xml

My spring application is working on local machine properly. But, on deploying it on a VM, it is giving HTTP Status 404 error.

**On VM:**

**http://serverIP:8080/Project/index.jsp**

It is giving HTTP 404 error.

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>osivf</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>osivf</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.htm</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

indexController

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />


<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000"/>
</bean>


<!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />


<!--  <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>-->

<!--<bean id="dao" class="food.db.DAO" />-->
```

Can somebody please help me here?

Comment: please post your controller.

Comment: And what URL is giving the 404

Comment: http://serverIP:8080/Project/index.jsp or http://serverIP:8080/index.htm or http://serverIP:8080/Project/index.htm. All are giving 404 error.

Comment: @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/index")
    public ModelAndView index()
    {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
        return mv;
    }

Answer (score 0):

you are accessing the deployed application with in the VM than you donot need the VM ip , try with 
`http://localhost:8080/Project/index.jsp`

if you want to access the deployed application on vm from your local system, than you need to forward the port from vm to local system like

step 1. open the vm setting 
Step 2. Go to the Network tab .
Step 3. In forwarded port need to define host port 8080 and guest port 8080
 
Step 4. start the VM.

`http://<VM IP>:8080/Project/index.jsp`

Comment: Actually, I am trying to host it on EC2 VM. On my local machine, Below is url. http://localhost:8080/index.htm. But, same is not working on EC2 VM

Comment: I am using tomcat server on ec2 VM for hosting it. I put my war file into webapps folder. And started tomcat server. http://serverIP:8080/index.jsp will give default tomcat page. I tried accessing my application page with http://serverIP:8080/Project/index.jsp or http://serverIP:8080/Project/index.htm, Both are giving 404 error.

Comment: serverIP is accessible from your system..? And are you able to see the tomcat home page after starting the tomcat server?.

Comment: Yes. Server IP is pingable. And able to see the tomcat home page.

Comment: while you start the tomcat on ec2 , please check the logs as well, is the application deploy successful or not ??

Comment: Tomcat is running properly. "service tomcat7 start". This will start the tomcat service on EC2 linux VM. I am able to see tomcat home page.

Comment: you need to check the tomcat server log while starting the tomcat because you have copy the war file into the webapps folder in the tomcat directory right so you need to check the log while starting the log and let me know the application is deployed successfully or not ..??

Comment: Yeah checked the logs. There was some version conflict. Resolved. Thanks for your help.